# How to fill dynamically-created SVGs (checking DOM is updated)

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I have some inline svgs with paths of class "paintstroke". I insert them as part of a larger function, and then I wish to fill them afterwards. The trouble is, I don't think the DOM is ready at the time this code is called (immediately after the svg creation), so nothing happens.

```
var paths = document.getElementsByClassName("paintstroke");
for(var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
    paths[i].style.fill = colors[i];
}
```

If I do a `setTimeout` before calling the above block it generally works, but occasionally misses a few svgs and is obviously a hacky solution. How can I check that all my `.paintstroke` objects are ready before trying to fill them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check that all my .paintstroke objects are ready before trying to fill them?

You can use the *old* `DOMNodeInserted` event: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxbn04ec/)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("paintstroke")) {
        // do the trick here.
    }
});
```

Please note that this solution will not work on IE < 10

UPDATE: based on comments, a [working example with SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/vpxhs97k/3/)

Comment: or document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});

Comment: Neither of these work. There is no event fired when svgs are added using `document.createElement()`(I tested with a simple `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {alert("boom!");});`

Comment: @Escher you can't add svgs with createElement, you need to use createElementNS perhaps that's your real problem.

Comment: Actually, I add various svgs as imgs using createElement, then convert them to inline using a bit of javascript. The svgs appear just fine as part of the DOM upon inspection, and display correctly, just filled black.

Comment: @rnrneverdies, thanks very much for the fiddle. I'll look at it soon, just snowed under with another project at the same time...

Comment: @rnrneverdies thanks, very helpful solution. For future passers-by, here is the fiddle hopefully demonstrating what I was trying to do in the question: https://jsfiddle.net/vpxhs97k/4/